# VBA Script not recognizing certain image types

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to run scripts that edit images automatically in a powerpoint presentation. There is no issue with the scripts themselves, they work great, but for some reason some of the images are unaffected by the script. I'll include the code to show how many object types I have tried to call. None of them work.

```
Sub ImageTablePosition()

Dim osld As Slide
Dim oshp As Shape
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

    With ActivePresentation.PageSetup
     x = .SlideWidth / 4
     y = .SlideHeight / 2
     Z = .SlideWidth - (0.25 * .SlideWidth)
    End With

    For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oshp In osld.Shapes

        If oshp.Type = msoPicture _
        Or oshp.Type = msoMedia _
        Or oshp.Type = msoGraphic _
        Or oshp.Type = msoLinkedGraphic _
        Or oshp.Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject _
        Or oshp.Type = msoLinkedPicture Then
        
            oshp.Left = x - (oshp.Width / 2)
            oshp.Top = (y - (oshp.Height / 2)) + 36
        End If
        If oshp.Type = msoTable Then
            oshp.Left = Z - (oshp.Width / 2) - 36
            oshp.Top = (y - (oshp.Height / 2)) + 36
        End If

Next
Next

End Sub
```

The only thing that did work was by using msoPlaceholder, but that moves the text, too. At this point, I really could just change the ones remaining in maybe 20 minutes, but it's more about me being genuinely curious why this is the case. If it helps, some of the images were uploaded to a media upload box available in the Powerpoint template, while most were simply copy and pasted in. I was wondering if that was the difference, where the ones uploaded to that box are considered something else. Thank you.

Comment: What _Type_ does these shapes/picture have?

Comment: Are some of the pictures in a group? When you loop over the shapes of a slide and you have groups (type = `msoGroup`), you will not catch the shapes *inside* the group.

Comment: Why not `Debug.Print oshp.Type` to check if you're missing some types in your `If ... Or ...` statement.

Comment: One of the most important things I have learned is to use the Locals window. Try and run your macro with f8, step by step, and look at the values that will come up at these lines: `For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides` and `For Each oshp In osld.Shapes`. In `osld` you will already be able to see all shapes in the slide and their types, once in `oshp` you will have individual information.

Comment: @Shrotter I used Super Symmetry's suggestion and found that some of the images (presumably these) are assigned to value 14, which I found to correspond to the placeholder object type, which explains why it worked when I called that type in the statement. Not sure why just these ones are tagged as such. Any idea how to change these objects into image type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to check the placeholder types using `PlaceholderFormat.Type`. I suggest you encapsulate the checking in a predicate as follows (**not tested**):

```vb
Sub ImageTablePosition()

  Dim osld As Slide
  Dim oshp As Shape
  Dim x As Long
  Dim y As Long

  With ActivePresentation.PageSetup
    x = .SlideWidth / 4
    y = .SlideHeight / 2
    Z = .SlideWidth - (0.25 * .SlideWidth)
  End With

  For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
      If IsShapeWatched(oshp) Then
        oshp.Left = x - (oshp.Width / 2)
        oshp.Top = (y - (oshp.Height / 2)) + 36
      
      ElseIf oshp.Type = msoTable Then
        oshp.Left = Z - (oshp.Width / 2) - 36
        oshp.Top = (y - (oshp.Height / 2)) + 36
      End If
    Next oshp
  Next osld

End Sub


Function IsShapeWatched(shp As Shape) As Boolean
  Dim watchedShapeTypes As Variant
  Dim watchedPlaceholderTypes As Variant
  Dim v As Variant
  
  '* Edit these arrays as needed
  watchedShapeTypes = Array(msoPicture, msoMedia, msoGraphic, msoLinkedGraphic, msoEmbeddedOLEObject, msoLinkedPicture)
  watchedPlaceholderTypes = Array(ppPlaceholderBitmap, ppPlaceholderMediaClip, ppPlaceholderPicture)
  
  If shp.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
    For Each v In watchedPlaceholderTypes
      If shp.PlaceholderFormat.Type = v Then
        IsShapeWatched = True
        Exit Function
      End If
    Next v
  Else
    For Each v In watchedShapeTypes
      If shp.Type = v Then
        IsShapeWatched = True
        Exit Function
      End If
    Next v
  End If
  
  IsShapeWatched = False
End Function
```

Note: You can find placeholder types [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.ppplaceholdertype)

Comment: Ah sweet, that works, thanks! Didn't even consider that there were different placeholder types. Appreciate your help! Also, if anyone else is struggling with their images being considered placeholders, I did some research -- The placeholder tag applies to anything that was inserted as part of the powerpoint template. That means text boxes and, in my case, images that were uploaded using a picture upload box in the template. In the first place, the picture upload template sucked and cut off a lot of the image automatically, so I'd generally recommend against using it.